# Excel 2013 macro to filter by multiple selected values

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to implement a macro which does the following:

If I select one or more cells belonging to the same column and activate the macro, then all rows which have not one of the selected values in the same column will be filtered out.

I. e., if the macro would be activated in the following table:

[image: Original Table]

this would result in the following filtered table:

[image]

So far, I could manage to implement a piece of code which works fine if only one cell is selected:

```
Range(ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address).AutoFilter Field:=ActiveCell.Column,Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
```

Could someone please help me to extend that code such that it is not limited to only one selected cell?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Please checkout this forum [macro-delete-rows-except-selected-rows](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/690937-macro-delete-rows-except-selected-rows.html#post3417170).. hope it helps

Comment: Does not really do what I need but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FilterMultipleCriteria()
    Dim filterRange As Range, filterValues() As Variant, cl As Range, i As Integer

    Set filterRange = Range("A1:C10") //Update the range as per your spreadsheet
    ReDim filterValues(Selection.Cells.Count - 1)
    i = 0

    For Each cl In Selection
        filterValues(i) = cl.Text
        i = i + 1
    Next cl

    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=filterValues, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. Based on your post I could come up with the following solution which seems to work fine:

```
Sub FilterMultipleCriteria()
    Dim filterValues() As Variant, cl As Range, i As Integer
    ReDim filterValues(Selection.Cells.Count - 1)
    i = 0
    For Each cl In Selection
        filterValues(i) = cl.Text
        i = i + 1
    Next cl
    Range(ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Address).AutoFilter Field:=ActiveCell.Column, 
    Criteria1:=filterValues, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that works. More generic than mine as not hard coding the column. Good work!